Naming convention for dotnet docker images tags - dash one
On this page https://mcr.microsoft.com/en-us/product/dotnet/sdk/tags we can see that all tags have additional -1 like for example mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0.302-1-jammy.
Can someone explain what is the meaning -1.
I see that there is also mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0.302-jammy but it is not listed here https://mcr.microsoft.com/en-us/product/dotnet/sdk/tags and has different SHA than mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0.302-1-jammy.
I would like to understand why the second tag is not listed on this page but it is available for the docker pull and what is the reason of -1.

I could only find this documentation of the tagging system and that doesn't explain the extra 1.

The -<n> tag suffix is used for unexpected out-of-band updates, such as hot fixes. This is described in the tags policy:

In the rare event that .NET components are updated before the next regular .NET service release, then a new image with a -1 tag will be created. The same practice will repeat itself if necessary (with -2 and then -3 tags).

For this specific instance, this tag was used in response to a PowerShell fix: Hotfix Release for PowerShell Update.
Feel free to post specific questions on the .NET Docker images at https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/discussions.
